# Marshalling list of lists using jaxb

Tags: java, jaxb

I have created a class like this

```
 @XmlRootElement(name="mylist")

public class JaxbList<T>{

@XmlElementWrapper(name="list")
@XmlElement(name="Item")
    protected List<T> list;

    public JaxbList(){}

    public JaxbList(List<T> list){
        this.list=list;
    }
        public List<T> getList(){       
        return list;
    }
}
```

This is main class:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("COlumn 1");
    list.add("COlumn 2");
    list.add("COlumn 3");

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    JaxbList jaxbList = new JaxbList(list);
    PDFHandler handler = new PDFHandler();

    try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = handler.getXMLSource(jaxbList);
        handler.createPDFFile(baos, "");
        System.out.println(jaxbList);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This is my marshalling method:

```
public ByteArrayOutputStream getXMLSource(JaxbList jaxbList) throws Exception {
    JAXBContext context;

    ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    try {
        context = JAXBContext.newInstance(JaxbList.class);
        Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
        m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
        m.marshal(jaxbList, outStream);
    } catch (JAXBException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return outStream;

}
```

The marshalling method creates the following XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<mylist>
    <list>
        <Item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">COlumn 1</Item>
        <Item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">COlumn 2</Item>
        <Item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">COlumn 3</Item>
    </list>
</mylist>
```

Now I want to marshall a list of lists:

```
protected List<List<String>> list
```

The XML output should look like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<mylist>
    <list>
        <Item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">COlumn 1</Item>
        <Item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">COlumn 2</Item>
        <Item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">COlumn 3</Item>
    </list>
<list>
        <Item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">COlumn 1</Item>
        <Item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">COlumn 2</Item>
        <Item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">COlumn 3</Item>
    </list>
</mylist>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried to work with List<List<String>> ? If you show us what you've tried, someone will probably help.  Much more likely than someone writing the code for you from scratch.

Comment: I m not getting idea to build a code for marshalling list of lists. Any hint will really help me to build a code. thank you

Answer (score -1):

Here's a sample:

```
public class Test{
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlRootElement(name = "mylist")
    static class MyList<T> {

        @XmlAnyElement
        protected Collection<Collection<T>> list;

        public MyList() {
        }

        public MyList(Collection<Collection<T>> list) {
            this.list = list;
        }

        public Collection<List<T>> getList() {
            return list;
        }
    }

    @XmlRootElement(name = "sublist")
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    static class List<T> {
        @XmlAnyElement
        protected Collection<T> sublist;

        public Collection<T> getSublist() {
            return sublist;
        }

        public void setSublist(Collection<T> sublist) {
            this.sublist = sublist;
        }

        public List() {
        }
    }

    @XmlRootElement
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    static class Item {
        @XmlValue
        private String value;

        public Item(){

        }
        public Item(String value){
            this.value = value;
        }

        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try {
            context = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyList.class, List.class, Item.class);
            Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
            m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
            m.marshal(jaxbList, System.out);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this code is incomplete and contains some errors. to me it's not clear how it actually would have to look. e.g `jaxbList` never defined. Why is `Item` marked as XMLRootElement? ...